# How to update an already set session with data?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session

I want to update a session array with the urls of the photos I have uploaded.

So far I have been able to create the session and add the array but I am unable to update the array and append further image urls to it.

How can I update a session with news data without overwriting the existing.

This is my code:

```
$show_photos = array('photo_url' =>'/assets/img/user_photos/thumbs/'.$image_data['file_name']);

$this->session->set_userdata('show_photos', $show_photos);
```

I am using the codeigniter framework but the same logic should still apply. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: I don't think out-of-the-box PHP sessions work this way. Are you using `CodeIgniter`?

Comment: Yep http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `set_userdata` method overwrites the session contents. So, to append to session var you'll have to explicitly do this:

```
//get old value
$old_val = $this->session->userdata('show_photos');
//append to it
$old_val[] = array('photo_url' =>'/assets/img/user_photos/thumbs/'.$image_data['file_name']);
//place it back
$this->session->set_userdata('show_photos', $old_val);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the php superglobal [`$_SESSION`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).

In your case `$_SESSION['show_photos']` holds your array and you can simply append data using:

`$_SESSION['show_photos'][] = array('your new data...');`

Comment: This doesn't use CodeIgniter's session methods as the questioner is using.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 $_session['show_photos'][] =  $show_photos;
```

where $show_photos is the next element to array

Comment: This doesn't use CodeIgniter's session methods as the questioner is using.

Comment: my bad.. i didn't notice the question was about CodeIgniter